# Load Image From Api And Cache It

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I am getting the image from api which i created a Gson model for to get the items, now i try loading the image on glide but it's not showing, the image response looks like this

```
"image":"2017\/Oct\/1507106147_IMG-20171003-WA0003.jpg"
```

i just want to know how to cache the image so that it can be displayed and scroll smoothly on listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's valid url/model to load your image. 
If your image is on server, you must make sure you get the right url to access it like this one:

```
"image":"https://www.blog.google/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png"
```

or maybe you get just a piece of it but you still need to make it become full link so it can be accessed, like this one:

```
"image":"/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png"

String base_url = "https://www.blog.google/static/blog/";
String full_url = base_url + image;
```

Comment: OK, thank you I will check that out later in 4hrs it already took my whole night! I suspected that but I am not the back end developer, but I will check now, thanks.